# Java Invalid escape sequences

Tags: java, command, exec, command-window

I have this error : "Invalid escape sequences (valid ones are \b \t ..." in my code Java.

I make in my code.java :

```
    ...
    r.exec("cmd /c D:\Doc and Settings\USER\Bureau\Apps-Two.loc.nal");
    ...
```

The problem is the escapes.
How resolve this problem ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
r.exec("cmd /c D:\Doc and Settings\USER\Bureau\Apps-Two.loc.nal"); // Compiler not able to understand this backslash.
```

you should use "\\" wherever you want to use actual backslash (\)

change your folder path like this

r.exec("cmd /c D:\\oc and Settings\\USER\\Bureau\\Apps-Two.loc.nal");

See the attached table for your reference

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You just have to escape the escaping character :

```
r.exec("cmd /c D:\\Doc and Settings\\USER\\Bureau\\Apps-Two.loc.nal");
```

See [Escape Sequences for Character and String Literals](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.6) :

```
EscapeSequence:
    \ b    /* \u0008: backspace BS */
    \ t    /* \u0009: horizontal tab HT */
    \ n    /* \u000a: linefeed LF */
    \ f    /* \u000c: form feed FF */
    \ r    /* \u000d: carriage return CR */
    \ "    /* \u0022: double quote " */
    \ '    /* \u0027: single quote ' */
    \ \              /* \u005c: backslash \ */
    OctalEscape        /* \u0000 to \u00ff: from octal value */
```

Comment: your IDE can do it for you autmatically. IntelliJ IDEA does it automatically by default and Eclipse can be configured to escape strings, see: http://vasanth.in/2009/03/10/eclipse-tip-escape-text-when-pasting/